# Event.Invoke() Not Firing All Events

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, invoke

So i have a simple event:

```
public delegate void TestEvent();
public TestEvent Test;
```

Then im defining the event in 1xclass & 1xcontrol using. (One updated the backend settings, while the other updates the UI.)

```
Test += TestRun;
```

Now if i fire the event from the main UI thread, using:

```
Test?.Invoke();
```

It works just fine. Both events fire & it updates properly. Great. But if i fire it from the background thread the UI Event never gets raised (but the background one does).

Does anyone know of why this is occuring & how to ensure the event fires on all threads?

p.s.
I have got this Dispatcher code in the UI event, to ensure no cross thread updates occur.

```
if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
   Dispatcher.Invoke(new TestEvent(TestRun));
   return;
}
```

Thanks a lot

Ian Chapple

Comment: Replace `Dispatcher.Invoke(new TestEvent(TestRun));` with `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Test?.Invoke());`. Basically inside the  `Dispatcher.Invoke` you should do exactly the same as when no `Invoke` is needed.

Comment: Why are you exposing a delegate instead of exposing a event?